# Firebase permission denied if there are pending writes after unauthenticating

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I have an issue in my Firebase app and was wondering if anybody has come up with any strategies around this issue.

If I have any pending writes that were initiated by an authenticated user to a firebase location with security rules requiring an authenticated user, if a user decides to unauthenticate, I will have a permission denied error for any of writes that were pending at the time of unauthentication.

I'm currently testing this by authenticating my user, entering airplane mode on my device, doing a write, then unauthenticating, as part of a process to switch users. I imagine this issue would come up if a user has a slow connection.

Has anybody come up with any strategies to work around this issue, or is this just the way Firebase works, and something I will have to expect?

Comment: If you're looking to switch users within your app then this is indeed unavoidable. The Firebase SDK is primarily a single-user-at-a-time client, the queued writes are not associated with a specific user XYZ, but rather with the current-user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just a thought; is there any way to leverage purgeOutstandingWrites if the user unauthenticated or perhaps by watching the isConnected flag?

Comment: You could listen for `.info/authenticated` (or just `observeAuthEventWithBlock`) and purge the writes then. I've never tested for race conditions there though, so ymmv.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any option before calling unauth to check .info/connected and have some way to know there are pending writes? Then at least you could keep the user authenticated on the client until the outstanding writes are sync'd back to firebase.